# Auto decrease numbers of z-index in javascript using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to auto decrease z-index numbers of a div in javascript using jquery?
If i set z-index to -2 then i want to auto down/decrease the z-index number like : -3,-4,-5

**Javascript**

```
var index = -2;
$timer = $('<div style="z-index://auto decrease index numbers//">');
```

Comment: your question is unclear

Comment: @userknowmore - z-index is not a basic property to set in css. Before you set z-index property position should be declared if it obsolute or relative then only z-index works.

Comment: Hey I am not downvote your question. I am only upvote all the time if it is right

Comment: downvoter may be anyone if someone feels that question is not useful.

Comment: @userknowmore - Bhojendra Nepal told true

Comment: see my question now clear

Comment: Ok i voteup bcz it working but i need more easier.Thanks @BhojendraNepal

Answer (score 1):

You can use setInterval method:

```
var dec = -2;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
   if(dec == -10){//if z-index is -10
     clearInterval(interval);//stop decreasing
   }
   $('.index').css('z-index',--dec);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$('.index').css('z-index', '-2');
```

The above code will set the *z-index* of all matching class to *-2*

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval(function(){$('.index').css('z-index', '-=1')}, 1000)`

Will -1 from the z-index of all `.index` elements once per second